# Display Grouped Items in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have searched everywhere for the code to display grouped items on a single-product.php. What im trying to do is display the child items on the parent grouped product. Anyone know what the snippet is to display those items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a product to grouped and save the children, it should be done automatically by woocommerce. See https://woocommerce.com/document/managing-products/#adding-a-grouped-product

Comment: was a cache issue. Wasn't displaying anything. Thanks